# Compress report files and send in mail

Tags: ruby

I have a test report file in HTML that is more than 10MB. I would like to know how to compress this file and send through mail. Zlib gem can compress and decompress. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: What OS? On Linux or Mac OS it's easy to use the command line tools to do that rather than write it in Ruby.

Comment: OS is Windows 7. No command line. Because it is manual. I want it to Automate. I run my regression scripts (ATDD fashion) for more feature files. Once all done, the test report file in HTML, should be compressed and send through mail. So that they can decompress (but dev & managers wont have Zlib gem) and see the results.

Comment: What have you tried? There are many pages and questions that discuss this sort of action and asking for us to recommend gems or off-site resources is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Instead, you are supposed to do the research, try things, and then ask specific questions about any problems you've encountered.